# Total number of AWS VPC limit per root account

Tags: aws-vpc

I looking for an AWS environment architecture where I can have more than 500 VPC. I do not see any AWS documentation where it has mentioned the VPC limit per root AWS account. From VPC FAQ it is clear that one account ( not root account ) can have only 5 VPC. Is there a limit for a number of VPC? 
I am looking for AWS multi-tenant service where I may have 500 tenants if the business grows. Just want to be in the right direction before designing single VPC per customer/tenant. I am new to AWS and any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Sas

Answer (score 1):

The account limit for vpc per region is 5. Its for the root account only.

Please check the respective docs from amazon aws at [Amazon VPC limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html)

But, you can still ask for increase of VPC by creating case at:

[Create case for increase in vpc limit](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-vpc)

**Sample case form**:

[image]